# "Hot embers" and "cold ice". Is this a figure of speech?

Tags: word-request, phrase-usage, usage, figurative-language

I've often come across phrases such as "hot embers" and "cold ice" (I'd be hard pressed to cite sources...I don't remember any). I found the adjectives "hot" and "cold" used with "embers" and "ice" respectively redundant, because...well... that (burning) embers are "hot" and that ice is "cold" is painfully obvious.

But since I see such usage *fairly* often (once again, I can't cite any sources), coupled with the existence of an establish term "paleo-achaeology", my initial belief that these were products of the airheaded-ness that usually grips users of the English language (joke) was reduced to mere suspicion.

Which is why I ask:

**Is this a figure of speech? If so what is it called? Moreover, what purpose does it serve? (sarcasm? emphasis?)**

Comment: Please tell us what you think the term _figure of speech_ connotes.

Comment: @P.E Um, something along the lines of "more than just literal"? Ah heck, I think this *might* be a "figure of speech" because an *oxymoron* is also considered a "figure of speech"...and what I'm asking for is...well...probably in the same category as oxymorons. 0:)

Comment: _Hot embers_ is an oxymoron? Do you understand what an oxymoron is? How are the noun _ember_ and the adjective _hot_ contradictory?

Comment: @P.E *Sigh* Rephrasing: Oxymorons are considered a "Figure of speech". So if the use of two words that are opposite in meaning side by side counts as a figure of speech, couldn't the (unnecessary) use of two words that relate to the same idea/quantity *also* be considered a "Figure of speech"? <----- Is what I meant o_o

Comment: What is connoted by the typographic element "o_o"?

Comment: @P.E It "connotes" someone staring at you till you feel intimidated ;)

Comment: I've heard "hot embers" many a time, but never "cold ice" (outside of its technical meaning).  Embers can be relatively cool or relatively hot. I don't consider it pleonasm. Wet water would be pleonasm.

Comment: Are you sure you're not thinking of _ice cold_ or _cold as ice_, rather than _cold ice_?

Comment: @Steve Yeah I'm sure. "...as he clutched at the cold ice..." :P

Comment: @paracetamol An example :o!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I don't think they're figures of speech since figures of speech are not meant to be taken literally. I believe these are *pleonasms* (bold emphasis mine):

> [Pleonasm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm) (/ˈpliːənæzəm/; from Greek πλεονασμός (pleonasmós), from πλέον (pleon), meaning 'more, too much') is the use of more words or parts of words than are necessary or sufficient for clear expression: examples are *black darkness*, *burning fire*. Such redundancy is, by traditional rhetorical criteria, a manifestation of tautology. That being said, **people may use a pleonasm for emphasis or because the phrase has already become established in a certain form.**
>   (Wikipedia)

Here are a couple of examples:

> 2. Semantic Pleonasm
>
> The semantic pleonasm is related more to the style of the language than the grammar such as given below.
>
> > “I am eating tuna fish burger.”
>
> Here tuna is itself a name of fish, and there is no need to add word “fish”.
>   Therefore, the word fish is pleonastic in the sentence.
>
> Examples of Pleonasm from Literature
>   Example #1
>
> > “This was the most unkindest cut of all…..”
>
> (Julius Caesar by William Shakespeare)
>
> In this extract, Shakespeare has deliberately used the term “most unkindest” as pleonastic. He could have used unkindest only; however, most is added in order to emphasize and give an even clearer meaning.
>   ([Literary Devices](https://literarydevices.net/pleonasm/))

Comment: "Black darkness", "Burning fire"... precisely what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: +1 @Max Pleonasms are exactly what they are, although I'm not sure that they are intended as such by the "airheads" who have elicited the OP's interest.

Comment: @Max Oh well, your answer *is* pretty much what I was looking for...but I suppose I'll give it a day before (re)accepting it. Thanks again O modest soul! :D

Comment: @paracetamol I would be a bit careful before calling these straight out pleonasms. A fire doesn't need to necessarily "burn" it can "smolder" it can even be "extinguished", "The extinguished fire showed someone must have been in the cabin a short while ago," is a perfectly valid sentence (though clumsy). And you can have "dying embers" which are quite different from "hot embers".

Comment: @paracetamol I think the usual point of these "obvious" adjectives is to do exactly what adjectives normally do paint a more vivid picture for the reader. There is a difference in the image if I write "The fire in the hearth burned brightly bathing the room in a warm orange glow," as opposed to, "There was a fire in the hearth."